# Free world flags 4:3 dimensions

Tags: data-request, images

Similar to [this request](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/free-icons-of-country-flags-reusable-in-both-open-source-and-commercial-product), I need some flag images (not icons) with uniform dimensions (preferably 4:3). All the flag libraries I've found all have non-uniform dimensions. Does anyone know of a free resource that caters for my need?

Comment: Most flags have different dimensions by official specifications, and one isn't even rectangular. You could either crop or stretch them to fit your needs. In some cases though (in Brazil), it's even illegal to change the proportions of the flag.

Comment: That being said, the UN and Olymics seem to fly all flags (except for Nepal) in the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a suitable library. Flags in both 4:3 and 1:1. I hope this helps others. https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have found from my research

### Famfamfam

We have been using [famfamfam flags](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/legacy-icons/famfamfam-flags/) which are fixed 16x11 icons but this icon set is rather outdated now.

### Emoji flags

With the adoption of unicode [emoji flags](https://emojipedia.org/flags/) we now have the opportunity to use fixed ratio icons at small pixel sizes. They fit and scale nicely alongside text.

The only caveat is that the flag is based on whatever font is installed so would have a different style other operating systems. For example on Windows emoji flag support seems to only just be catching up now but may require polyfill to avoid only showing letters.

### Flags from fonts

If you want a uniform flag image we can still directly utilise the flag files from open-source emoji fonts. If using country codes as lookup these filenames will need renamed back from unicode code points ([code example](https://gist.github.com/cas--/8e3083291cbef3089a673fd849ac39fc)). Granted this is a bit more work but they are an actively maintained source of flags.

#### Noto Color Emoji

[Noto Color Emoji](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji/glyphs) has nice 5:3 ratio [waved flags](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/third_party/region-flags/waved-svg) in SVG that can scaled to any size. These images are sourced from Wikimedia then simplified with [picosvg](https://github.com/googlefonts/picosvg) and [warp added](https://github.com/rsheeter/warp).

#### Twemoji Color Font

[Twemoji Color Font](https://github.com/13rac1/twemoji-color-font) again has fixed ratio flags as SVG. Flag files  names start at `1f1e6-1f1e8.svg`.

### Examples

Here is the Andorra flag for comparison for the above options.

- [image] Famfamfam
- [Emoji Flag](https://emojipedia.org/flag-andorra/)
- [image] Noto Color Emoji (16px png)
- [image] Twemoji